# Android Wake up app on bluetooth keyboard key pressed

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard, intentfilter, wakeup

I'm trying to develop an app that recognizes when a paired bluetooth keyboard's key is pressed and wakes up the app with certain action. The bluetooth device in particular is the Selfie Remote Shutter (this one, no ads intended: http://www.ebay.es/itm/like/361219097614) and it's recognized by the device as a bluetooth keyboard. It sends two different events which the SO in Android identifies as **key volume up pressed** and **enter key pressed**.

I've declared a receiver for my app and tried to listen to every bluetooth action in order to identify the command sent from the keyboard to my device, capture that event and trigger certain method in my app, even if it's not open.

I don't know how to achieve this, since when the app is opened, I can override the **onKeyDown** event and recognize which "key" has the bluetooth keyboard pressed, but can't figure how to achieve that with the app closed. Maybe some intent-filter?

Thanks in advance!